# Как ограничить скорость обьекта по горизонтальным осям в Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, физика

У меня есть скрип который уже ограничивает скорость объекта, но он также ограничивает и вертикальную скорость, а мне это не нужно - только горизонтальную. Вот скрипт (CS)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpeedBorder : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody Obj;

    [SerializeField] private float _MaxSpeedOfObj = 10;

    private void Awake() {
        Obj = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if (Obj.velocity.magnitude >= _MaxSpeedOfObj) { Obj.velocity = Obj.velocity.normalized * _MaxSpeedOfObj; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так ограничивай не длину всего вектора скорости, а его конкретную ось.

Answer (score 0):

Если объект перемещается при нажатии клавиш, то можно просто изменять скорость, когда объект перемещается в определенную сторону.

Например.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpeedBorder : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody Obj;

    [SerializeField] private float _MaxSpeedOfObj = 10;
    private float _defaultVelocity = 10;

    private void Awake() {
        Obj = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _defaultVelocity = Obj.velocity;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if (Input.GetKey("a") || Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            if (Obj.velocity.magnitude >= _MaxSpeedOfObj) { Obj.velocity = Obj.velocity.normalized * _MaxSpeedOfObj; }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("w") || Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            if (Obj.velocity != _defaultVelocity) 
            {
                Obj.velocity = _defaultVelocity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).